# Cisco Networking fiber to fiber

Tags: networking, cisco

I have a cisco 892 router and a cisco catalyst 2960 switch; both have the SFP fiber module.  The plan is to extend the network to the switch using the fiber ports. (Two buildings are connected by fiber)  No routing is needed, just to connect the switch to the router via the fiber ports. I tried to set  the sfp interface to switchport access, but it gives an error – I think it may only support WAN connectivity.

So in a nutshell. I am trying to connect one building to another over fiber. The Cisco routers do not have a fiber port so I had to use a sfp interface to convert the fiber to ethernet. I am trying to get the switch in building A to talk to the router in building B.   I think the problem is I am using the SFP module and it is in an expansion slot on the router and switch and not actually plugged into one of the ports on the switch and router. All I am trying to do is bridge the connections so building A can be apart of building Bs network.

Comment: Are you saying you want to turn the router into a bridge?

Comment: You say it gives an error - what's the error. It's best if you provide complete data.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand this correctly. You already have a network in place in building #1 and want to extend it to building #2 via fiber.

I'm assuming you have a 1000base-T switch in building #1 and it is lacking sfp-ports. To mitigate this problem you want to use an 892 you have laying around as a bridge to gain a fiber connectivity in building #1.

Unless the interface with the SFP module accepts the "switchport" command, it can't be done.

I would suggest you toss the 892 and use a media convert instead, e.g http://www.planet.com.tw/en/product/product.php?id=43643

Either that or buy a switch for building #1 with SFP support.